# Accesing USB device as a file

Tags: drivers, usb, usb-device

I have a USB thermometer that I used in Windows XP with the bundled drivers. It just reads the air temperature and the PC reads that value.

Now I want to use it under Linux, for example in a Raspberry Pi. I plugged it in and the only thing I have been able to figure out is to get the device information from syslog:

```
Jan 25 10:31:01 pi kernel: [  202.825771] usb 1-1.1.2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
Jan 25 10:31:01 pi kernel: [  202.916413] usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=413d, idProduct=2107
Jan 25 10:31:01 pi kernel: [  202.916443] usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Jan 25 10:31:01 pi kernel: [  202.922898] input: HID 413d:2107 as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2/1-1.1.2:1.0/0003:413D:2107.0004/input/input2
Jan 25 10:31:01 pi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2"
Jan 25 10:31:01 pi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Jan 25 10:31:01 pi kernel: [  202.976409] hid-generic 0003:413D:2107.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [HID 413d:2107] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.2/input0
Jan 25 10:31:01 pi kernel: [  202.981627] hid-generic 0003:413D:2107.0005: hiddev96,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [HID 413d:2107] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.2/input1
Jan 25 10:31:01 pi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2"
Jan 25 10:31:01 pi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device
```

As I don't have the skills to code a driver, I thought that using the files in that log I could read the data, like I usually do with files in `/proc` or `/dev`, but I don't understand those files and directories.

Is this possible? Does it help that Linux identifies the device as a HID device?

Comment: A driver and appropriate software is what is lacking.

Comment: Oh, https://github.com/shakemid/pcsensor-temper has something to start with btw.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't recognize the device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [temperx/temperx.go](https://github.com/mreymann/temperx) project which supports your USB device 413d:2107.

**temperx** is a Munin plugin written in PHP using the hid-query binary provided by [TEMPered](https://github.com/edorfaus/TEMPered).

**temperx.go** is a standalone tool written in Go that reports current temperature and humidity.

I'd probably try the Go tool first which seems to be easier to install.

1. Install [Go](https://go.dev/doc/install)
2. Instructions taken from the project site:

   ```
   $ go get github.com/mreymann/temperx
   $ go install github.com/mreymann/temperx
   ```

   Should produce the `temperx` binary in `$GOPATH/bin/`

   Example:

   ```
   $ /root/go/bin/temperx
   Temperature: 23.33, Humidity: 40.6
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I got the Go tool working now. `pip install temper-py` also worked fine